# Long-term probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am in intro probability class, and I know the basics, such as conditional probability, and how to solve simple problems. However, how does one solve this problem (below) without knowing whether or not the plant actually flowered this year?

*The probability of a plant flowering next year given that it flowered this year is 0.9. 
The probability of it flowering next year given that it did not flower this year is 0.3. What is the long term probability of the plant flowering (to 2 decimal places)*

Comment: Do you know anything about Markov chains? If not, do you know anything about linear algebra? (You can answer the problem with neither of these, but the concept is clearer if you have at least one of them.)

Comment: The first step to the solution would be to realize that the "long-term" probability means the probability the plant will flower in some given year many, many years from now. The idea is that by that time, the plant's flowering status will have randomly changed (or not changed) so many times between now and then that the effect of this year's flowering or not-flowering will be negligible. Essentially, the probabilistic state of the plant cannot "remember" events that occurred very long ago.

Answer (score 2):

We have that for all $n>1$ , $\mathsf P(Y_n) ~=~ \mathsf P(Y_{n-1})\,\mathsf P(Y_n\mid Y_{n-1})+\mathsf P(Y_{n-1}^\complement)\,\mathsf P(Y_n\mid Y_{n-1}^\complement) \\ \qquad ~~~ = ~ 0.9\,\mathsf P(Y_{n-1})+0.3\,(1-\mathsf P(Y_{n-1}))$

Now in the long term, whatever the initial state, we will approach an equilibrium state.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(\mathsf P(Y_n)-\mathsf P(Y_{n-1})\big)~=~0$$

So the long term probability of it flowering in a year will be $~p~=~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(Y_n)~$

Find $p$.